# Como fazer o download de multiplos urls no R?

Tags: r, url

Preciso extrair vários arquivos textos que estão organizados em pastas anuais no seguinte url: http://www.rsssfbrasil.com/tablesae/

Como faço para extrair diversas pastas ao mesmo tempo? Por exemplo, se quero os arquivos de 2003, 2004 e 2005, para não precisar escrever o mesmo código três vezes.

Obrigada!

Comment: Olá, no endereço informado na pergunta, não encontrei nenhuma pasta ou diretório, apenas vários arquivos htm. Geralmente você vai baixar os arquivos somente uma vez, e depois trabalhar em cima deles. O que exatamente você quer fazer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Há várias maneiras; uma não muito elegante:

```
library(RCurl)
library(XML)

base = 'http://www.rsssfbrasil.com/tablesae/'

page = url(base)

download.file(base, destfile='test.html')
page = htmlTreeParse('test.html', useInternal=TRUE, asTree=TRUE)
links = xpathSApply(page, "//a", xmlGetAttr, name='href')

# pega apenas os links com 'htm'
links = links[grep('htm', links)]

for(link in links) {

  download.file(paste(base, link, sep=""), destfile=link)

}
```